# write date/time on each event line in log4net

Tags: xml, datetime, log4net

I use log4net for logging which is great, but I haven't figured out to write a valid datetime attribute on each event line. I use xml.  I see that there are a timestamp attribute but thats not usefull to me. My web.config file look like this....

```
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\log.xml" />

      <staticLogFileName value="false" />      

      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <locationInfo value="true" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Why is the timestamp not useful? I presume you are using some program to view the log files which should be able to easily convert this to a DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j type. I always use the PatternLayout type. This example has always worked for me to show the datetime, log level, logger, and message:

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger|%message%newline" />
  </layout>
```